# How to align button by vertically in div using JQuery/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following code:

#### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first_column">Sign in</td>
        <td class="second_column">->(1)</td>
        <td class="third_column"><div class="translated">Some text</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JS:

```
$(".translated").mouseenter(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("editable")){
        return;
    }
    var h=$(this).height();
    var w=$(this).width();
    $(this).empty();
    var field = $("<input/>", {
            type: "text",
            value:$(this).text()
        }).appendTo(this);
    var button = $("<button></button>").appendTo(this);
    field.height(h - field.outerHeight()+field.height());
    button.height(h-button.outerHeight()+button.height());
    $(this).height(h);
    $(this).width(w);
    $(this).addClass("editable");
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.translated
{
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

This code addes input and button items to div container when mouse focuses the div. But there is the following problem - button has got a good height, but incorrect align. I need that a new button item is in center of row by vertically. Please, tell me, how can I do it?

Comment: Please add the main HTML markup to your question so we can see what that looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set button width in your js code:

```
button.css('width', field.width());
```

try on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/velthune/NCrUu/5/

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code, added a table row and set the width of input and button. They are different because of the margins and paddings browsers give these elements

http://jsfiddle.net/andreaslyngstad/BFwU7/

HTML

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="first_column">Sign in</td>
                <td class="second_column">->(1)</td>
                <td class="third_column">
                  <div class="translated">Some text</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td class="first_column"></td>
                <td class="second_column"></td>
                <td class="third_column" id="button_container"></td>
            </tr>
 </table>​​​
```

CSS

```
table{
    width:100%
}
button{
    width:100px
}
input{
    width:96px
}
.translated {
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
  }​
```

JS

```
var field = $("<input/>", {
    type: "text",
    value: $(this).text()
})
var button = $("<button>sign in</button>")

$(".translated").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).empty();
    field.appendTo(this);
    button.appendTo($("#button_container"));
});​
```